# Infinity drag-n-move for StaggeredGridLayout when moving item upward

Tags: android

Currently, I'm performing drag-n-move on `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayout`, with guide from https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf

However, sometimes, I stuck in the following situation, especially, when I want to move an item upward. (Downward is OK)

1. Move the item from position 81 to position 68.
2. (Based on logging). Due to re-positioning item in `StaggeredGridLayout`, current drag position will become 81 again.
3. Continue to drag to position 68, step 1 and step 2 will keep repeating.

Please see the video https://webmshare.com/play/QRdwZ

Is there a way I can avoid such? Use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE` doesn't do any help.

I have tried my implementation on `LinearLayoutManager`, `GridLayoutManager`. They appears fine in both scrolling direction.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is related to the bug reported in [Move animation for StaggeredGridLayoutManager is broken when using DefaultItemAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49962959/move-animation-for-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-is-broken-when-using-defaultiteman) and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78373192